# Difference between sending elements individually or as array using WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

Let's say we have an REST end point `api.example.com/entities` that returns a list of entities matching an array of `ids`. To get entities with ids "1", "2" or "3" you can either call

```
api.example.com/entities?ids=1,2,3
```

or

```
api.example.com/entities?ids=1
api.example.com/entities?ids=2
api.example.com/entities?ids=3
```

Obviously we are using former option as it reduces overhead and TCP handshakes.

But what about WebSockets? The overhead is almost no-existent and the payload can actually be reduced when sending an entity individually.

The reason I am asking is that I want to stream data in my NodeJS app and send updates to clients immediately instead of waiting for the stream to finish.

What I do not want to do:

```
request('https://api.example.com/entities?ids=1,2,3')
.then((entities) => socket.emit('entities', entities));
```

What I want to do:

```
request('https://api.example.com/entities?ids=1,2,3')
.pipe(JSONStream.parse('entities.*'))
.on('data', (entity) => socket.emit('entity', entity));
```

In other words: I want to send out entities as soon as possible.

**What is the difference between sending elements individually or as array using WebSockets?**